# converting google slides into html not working

Tags: html

im trying to convert google slides into html code to have it in my website.
i've tried to use this code https://github.com/thejimbirch/GoogleDoc2Html/blob/master/code.js
to convert it through going into the tools menu and clicking script editor and then pasting the code in the window that appears. error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBody' of null

im new to coding and don't understand this, i've tried to find an answer myself but couldn't find anything.

please help